# Appended field values not submitted

Tags: php, jquery

I have a set of form fields in PHP. I also added jQuery functionality to clone some fields and add them to the form. However, after I submit the form only the original fields are submitted and not the ones added though cloning.

**PHP**

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action"...">
   <div class="row contRow">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="text" id="contactInputName['.$i.']" name="name['.$i.']" value="'.$output['0'].'" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">  &nbsp; &nbsp; 
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="contactInputEmail['.$i.']" name="email['.$i.']" value="'.trim($output['1']).'" class="emlVal form-control"> &nbsp; 
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 text-right">
            <span class="btn btn-default rmContact"><i class="fas fa-times fa-fw fa-lg text-danger"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <span id="saveContacts" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-check fa-fw fa-lg"></i> Save Contacts</span>
            <span id="addRow" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-fw fa-lg"></i> Add More</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on("click", "#addRow", function() {
    var lastRow = $("#addContactsForm").find(".contRow").last();
    lastRow.clone().insertAfter(lastRow);
    lastRow.find("input").val("");
});

$(document).on("click", "#saveContacts", function() {
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is `'.$i.'`?

Comment: And when you clone, `input`s have same `name`s as the last item, don't they?

Comment: Ohh, good catch. I build the fields via loop and modify the name based on the loop iterration... I need to fix this when I clone, dah...

Comment: I guess I need to grab numeric value of the name, increment and modify the cloned one. Right? How do I do that?

Comment: I don't know which framework you use but I suppose you want to distinct __new records__ from __existsing records__, don't you? Maybe then it makes sense to create a template for a new record and use it as a source for adding html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would remove `id="contactInputName['.$i.']"` and `id="contactInputEmail['.$i.']"` because I don't see the need to set these attributes.

If you set name attributes with empty keys, incremented keys will be generated for you. E.g.

```
name="name[]"
```

and

```
name="email[]"
```

This should eliminate the issue with copied indexes while cloning.